# Spark SQL selecting alias Column on UNION

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am doing a Union on a View with itself and then tried to select the alias column i created.

Here is the code i have:

```html
val mergedDF = sparkSession.sqlContext.sql(" SELECT COLUMN1 as COLUMN3 FROM MY_VIEW Union SELECT COLUMN2 as COLUMN3 from MY_VIEW")

val mergedView = mergedDF.createOrReplaceTempView("MERGED_VIEW")

val distinctColumnDF =sparkSession.sqlContext.sql(" SELECT distinct COLUMN3 from MERGED_VIEW WHERE node like '%city%')

logger.debug("No.of Distinct City Rows="+distinctColumnDF.count());
```

I am getting the following Error:

```html
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: mismatched input 'from' expecting { <EOF>, 'WHERE' , 'GROUP', 'ORDER', 'HAVING', 'LIMIT', 'LATERAL', 'WINDOW', 'UNION', 'EXCEPT', 'MINUS', 'INTERSECT','SORT','CLUSTER','DISTRIBUTE' }(line 1 , pos 21)

== SQL ==

SELECT distinct COLUMN3 from MERGED_VIEW where node like '%city%'
---------------------^^^^
```

Appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use alias method on dataframe like:

```
val dfA = sparkSession.sqlContext.sql("SELECT COLUMN1 FROM MY_VIEW")
val dfB = sparkSession.sqlContext.sql("SELECT COLUMN2 FROM MY_VIEW")     
val mergedDF = dfA.select(dfA.col("COLUMN1").alias("COLUMN3")).union(dfB.select(dfB.col("COLUMN2").alias("COLUMN3")))

val distinctColumnDF = mergedDF.filter(mergedDF.col("COLUMN3").contains("city")).distinct().collect()

logger.debug("No.of Distinct Rows="+distinctColumnDF.count());
```

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to be working.

```html
val dfA = sparkSession.sqlContext.sql("SELECT COLUMN1 FROM MY_VIEW")
val dfB = sparkSession.sqlContext.sql("SELECT COLUMN2 FROM MY_VIEW")     
val mergedDF = dfA.select(dfA.col("COLUMN1").alias("COLUMN3")).union(dfB.select(dfB.col("COLUMN2").alias("COLUMN3")))

val str = mergedDF.select(mergedDF.col("COLUMN3")).filter(mergedDF.col("COLUMN3").contains("test")).distinct().count()

logger.debug("No.of Distinct Rows="+str);
```

Not sure why the pure SQL Syntax didn't work.

Thanks FiagB for your suggestions.